# Programmatically adding Boundfield

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have question about adding BoundFiled to GridView. All about framework .net 2, higher is not possible. I have this code

```
BoundField column = new BoundField();
column.HeaderText = "XX";
column.DataField = "ID";
column.SortExpression = "ID";
column.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "titletext";
column.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Percentage(7);

TableCell tc = new TableCell();
tc.Controls.Add(column);
```

And last command return this error message

> *"The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.UI.ControlCollection.Add(System.Web.UI.Control)' has some
>   invalid arguments"*

This is what i using in c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
```

This example is from internet and doesn't work, thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add bound column as this

```
  BoundField boundField = new BoundField();
  boundField.DataField = "ID";
  boundField.HeaderText = "ID";
  boundField.SortExpression = "ID";
  boundField.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "titletext";
  boundField.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Percentage(7);
  GridView1.Columns.Add(boundField);
  //bind gridview..

  bindgridview();

 note: data source must contain the ID column
```

Comment: Thanks, works, and if i can change BoundField over onrowcommand to input mode? I can't use CommandField, because that reload all data, i can programmatically change one selected data to edit mode without CommandField. In HTML it looks like this, i change <td>text</td> to <td><input value="text" /></td>, but i don't know, how i do this in c#. Thank you

Comment: kindly put another question for this...and but all the details from here i cnt understand what is your requirement and what issue you are facing